# Install and activate a list of Equinox OSGI bundles at once at runtime

Tags: osgi-bundle, equinox

I am installing 3 bundles one by one into Equinox platform at run time by calling bundleContext.install("file") all three bundle states are *INSTALL* . if am calling start() on one bundle giving an error service not available that is in other bundle, that bundle not at started still in install state. so i want start those three at same time.

Comment: AFAIK, a bundle must first become RESOLVED before it can start.

Comment: yes your 100% correct . then how to RESOLVED i don't want Activate that bundles i want RESOLVE all at once

Comment: Sounds like a cyclic dependency. Bundles are always resolved one by one.